# how to integrate a file upload and model persistance using backbone and express

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, file-upload

I have tried to find a solution for the following but it does not seem to be obvious for a beginner. I am integrating a form upload using `backbone` and `express`. The form consists of a user information and a file upload. The idea is to upload the file and persist the user model to a database with a field referencing to a file.

Uploading a file using `express` can be easily implemented sending the form through `POST` with the proper HTML tags (`<form method='post' action='/upload' enctype='multipart/form-data'>`) and a simple handler like it is done in http://shivalibari.com/blog/2014/02/file-upload-using-node/.

In my case, however, I use a `backbone` view to handle the submit event and use `save()` to persist the model making a `POST` to express:

```
submit: function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = {};
  console.log("submit form");
  // read form...
  $('.form-group').children('input').each(function(i,el){
     if( $( el ).val() != '' )
       { 
           formData[ el.id ] = $( el ).val();
       }
  });

this.user = new User();
this.user.save(formData);

}
```

as simplified version of the `POST` handler...

```
var app = express();

app.post( '/api/users', function( request, response) {
  var user = new UserModel({
     name: request.body.name,
     email: request.body.email,
     file: request.body.file
  });

  user.save( function( err ) {
        if( !err ) {
            return console.log( 'created' );
        } else {
            return console.log( err );
        }
        return response.send( user );
  });
}
```

Any ideas of how to handle the file upload maybe before, after or during model persistence?
I'd like to minimize the use of plugins unless strictly necessary using `node.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own answer in the following blog post: http://estebanpastorino.com/2013/09/27/simple-file-uploads-with-backbone-dot-js/. The solution consists on using the iframe trick to pass the file objects to the server and can be easily implemented using a `jquery` plugin called `jquery.iframe-transport`.

This jquery plugin makes the file objects available on the server in the `request.files` attribute, which can be used to be read/write files as explained in http://shivalibari.com/blog/2014/02/file-upload-using-node/.

In my implementation I end up using two different models for the `user profile` and the `files`. I first synced the file model, and then used a success callback to sync the `user profile` model.